# Search query not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My search query not working when I search with empty field(String) it returns all result

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
{
    $skills=trim($_GET['skillset']);
    $city=trim($_GET['city']);
    $state=trim($_GET['state']);
    $expinmonth=trim($_GET['expinmonth']);

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from seeker where (skillset like '%$skills%') or (city like '%$city%') or (state like '%$state%') or  (expinmonth like '%$expinmonth%')");          

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo .$data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No Results';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check fields. If it is mandatory, you need to warn user, if not, you can search wildcard search as empty. It is not mandatory means bring all result for that column

Comment: show some sample-data that is contained in the table `seeker` and what parameters were given for the queries you tried for `skills, `city`, `state` and `expinmonth`

Comment: if some one skip all field there should be no result and if any field have data result should be according to field.

Comment: You need to check if string is empty: if(empty($_GET['skillset'])) and so on.. if some of these inputs is empty just show 'no results' message

Comment: you did not specify how your search should work exactly, when a field contains an empty string, does that mean to the user he does not care what content it has or that it should match that `empty string` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you are trying to do is check for blank fields when a field is skipped. In which case something like this:-

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
{
    $skills = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['skillset']));
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['city']));
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['state']));
    $expinmonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['expinmonth']));

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * 
                                from seeker 
                                where ".(($skills == '' ) ? "skillset = ''" : "skillset like '%$skills%'")."
                                or ".(($city == '' ) ? "city = ''" : "city like '%$city%'" )."
                                or ".(($state == '' ) ? "state = ''" : "state like '%$state%'")."
                                or ".(($expinmonth == '' ) ? "expinmonth = ''" : "expinmonth like '%$expinmonth%'")." ");          

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo .$data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No Results';
    }
}

?>
```

Further to the comment by DrCopyPaste, if you just want to ignore blank input:-

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
{
    $skills = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['skillset']));
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['city']));
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['state']));
    $expinmonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['expinmonth']));

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * 
                                from seeker 
                                where 1=2
                                ".(($skills != '' ) ? " OR skillset like '%$skills%'" : "")."
                                ".(($city != '' ) ? " OR city like '%$city%'" : "")."
                                ".(($state != '' ) ? " OR state like '%$state%'" : "")."
                                ".(($expinmonth != '' ) ? " OR expinmonth like '%$expinmonth%'" : "")." ");          

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo .$data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No Results';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I think for the case that variables contain empty strings no where condition should be added, as in most cases when in a search a field is not given (empty string) it means "i don't care about the contents of that field" so I would rewrite for example `".(($skills == '' ) ? "skillset = ''" : "skillset like '%$skills%'")."` into `".(($skills == '' ) ? "skillset = skillset" : "skillset like '%$skills%'")."` this would also require to rewrite the `OR`s into another logic using `AND`s; however both ways are just assuming, because OP did not specify how search logic should work in this case

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - I am unsure. Entirely possible you suggestion is correct, but without more details from the OP we can't know. If blank values were irrelevant then it would probably be easiest to put the OR into the inline IFs first result, and just put '' for the second (ie - ` ".(($state != '' ) ? "OR state like '%$state%'" : "")."`) , although this would need minor tweaks to cope with the WHERE keyword on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...Just a little change in your query

```
if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
{
    $skills=trim($_GET['skillset']);
    $city=trim($_GET['city']);
    $state=trim($_GET['state']);
    $expinmonth=trim($_GET['expinmonth']);

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from seeker where (skillset like '%$skills%' and skillset <> '') or (city like '%$city%' and city <> '') or (state like '%$state%' and state <> '') or  (expinmonth like '%$expinmonth%' and expinmonth <> '')");          

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo .$data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No Results';
    }
}
```

Comment: the check needs to be done the other way around (i.e. checking whether `$skills, $city, $state or $expinmonth` are empty strings, not the column contents itselves, this is because `LIKE '%$someVar%'` will always return true, if `$someVar` is an empty string, so this results in `LIKE '%%'` which matches any string